# Issue storing ref elements in loop

Tags: reactjs

When trying to store refs in an array inside a loop, I get weird results when the page re-renders (everything is as expected when the page first renders).

I reproduced the problem in this very small jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/68251/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      setTimeout(() => { this.setState({foo: 'bar'}); }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('--- RENDER ---');

    const divs = [];
    this.elements = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        divs.push(
            <div
                key={i}
                ref={(ref) => {
                    this.elements.push(ref);

                    console.log(this.elements);
                }}
            >
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {divs}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can see that when the page renders a second time, I suddenly get null values and end up with an array of 4 elements.

Could anyone explain why it behaves like that? Why is the function handling the ref executed 4 times after the second rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any
>   component. The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the
>   callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted
>   or unmounted.

So the reason why four ref callbacks are called is because two components are unmounted and two are mounted.

Comment: Thank you! Then what is the right way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I.e. store the refs of this set of elements (to be able to access their dom later on).

Comment: @Matthew No problem! `React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.` You could check `if (ref) { this.elements.push(ref); }`.