# React ref inside of a loop breaks on re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a gallery component that takes in an array of components. In each of the child components I am assigning a ref. The reason for this is because within the child component there are many other children components and I am attempting to access some functions on a component that is about 5 component deep. The below code shows the initial setup:

```
export class Gallery extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const galleryItems = data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <GalleryItem
                    ref={React.createRef()}
                />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div >
                <Gallery
                    items={heroGalleryItems}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When the Gallery component renders all the refs in the array of GalleryItem component are correct. But as soon as the Gallery component re renders for any reason the refs in the GalleryItem components become null values.

I have tried several things in the children components but nothing I do fixes the issue. I believe the reason is because something is happening in the code above.

I have also tried to change up the code after reading the following:

[Issue storing ref elements in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838833/issue-storing-ref-elements-in-loop)

However its not really clear to me what the person is saying to do when I look at my own implementation.

Comment: give key={index} to the `<GalleryItem />` in the loop, and let me know if it works?

Comment: My. apologies, I was holding back some of the code because of our company limitations. There is a prop key={index}

Comment: After reading the other post I was sure there was some kind of syntax that would easily solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move out `React.createRef(`) from the loop (and also render) as it is creating a new ref on every render.

Depending on your code/usage, you'd need to do this in constructor and CWRP methods (basically whenever data changes).

Then creating `galleryItems` would be like

```
...
<GalleryItem ref={item.ref} />
...
```